# Error in asMethod(object): Cholmod error 'problem too large'

Tags: r, large-data

I have the following object

```
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:120671481] 0 2 3 6 10 13 21 22 25 36 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:51366] 0 3024 4536 8694 3302271 3302649 5715381 5756541 5784009 5801691 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 10314738 51365
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10314738] "line1" "line2" "line3" "line4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:51365] "sparito" "davide," "15enne" "di" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".match.hash")=Class 'match.hash' <externalptr> 
  ..@ x       : num [1:120671481] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
```

This object comes from the function `dtm_builder` of `text2map` package. Since I would like to remove empty rows from the matrix, I thought about using the command:

```
raw.sum=apply(dtm,1,FUN=sum) #sum by raw each raw of the table
dtm2=dtm[raw.sum!=0,]
```

Anyway, I obtained the following error:

```
Error in asMethod(object): Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ..
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: Can you try `rowSums` i.e. `dtm[rowSums(dtm) !=0,]`   I created with a small example, but it was working.  maybe it is the size

Comment: Thank you @akrun. I tried it but with `rowSums(dtm) !=0` I obtained the following error: `Error in rowSums(dtm): 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`

Comment: sorry, I couldn't reproduce the error in a small data `m1 <- Matrix(1:9, 3, 3, sparse = TRUE);> rowSums(m1)#
[1] 12 15 18;
> rowSums(m1) != 0#
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE`

Comment: when i try with your dimensions, I got a memory limit error though `Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your problem is that you're likely converting a sparse object to a dense object. `Matrix` package sparse matrix classes are very memory efficient when a matrix has a lot of zeros (like a DTM) by simply not allocating memory for the zeros.

@akrun's answer should work, but there is a `rowSums` function in base R and a `rowSums` function from the Matrix package. You would need to load the Matrix package first.

Here is an example dgCMatrix (note not loading Matrix package yet)

```r
m1 <- Matrix::Matrix(1:9, 3, 3, sparse = TRUE)
m1[1, 1:3] <- 0
class(m1)
```

If we use the base R `rowSums` you get the error:

```r
rowSums(m1)
Error in rowSums(dtm): 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

If the Matrix package is loaded,`rowSums` will be replaced with the Matrix package's own method, which works with `dgCMatrix`. This is also true for the bracket operators `[`. If you update `text2map` to version 0.1.5, Matrix is loaded by default.

That is a massive DTM, so you may still run into memory issues -- which will depend on your machine. One thing to note is that removing sparse rows/columns will not help much. So, although words that occur once or twice will make up about 60% of your columns, you will reduce the size in terms of memory more by removing the most frequent words (i.e. words with a number in every row).